# Who am I? From the family Adams

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I am the biggest in my family. We are very close despite some living in different countries. Let me introduce us: We are the family Adams.
There are a lot of families like us: The Harrisons for example, they are less than us, but their fame resides in their big bodies. Our neighbours, the Rabeys, are very close to us and we are friends.
You mustn't confuse us with the family Aces; they are very famous too, but they live across the sea.

Back to me: some people think I'm a cold person, but it is not my fault! Some of my brothers are very dangerous when they get angry. I'm not like them but I could be dangerous if you don't know how to face me...
If you want to see me, I will wait for you in the same place like always...

Who or what am I?

Hint 1

> The surnames are fictional but they were not chosen randomly

Comment: Are the grammar and spelling mistakes in the text intentional?

Comment: Sorry for that. No, I'm not an English speaker so...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> [Aconcagua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aconcagua), the tallest mountain in the [Andes mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andes), the longest mountain continental mountain chain. It contains several glaciers, which, along with its altitude, make it cold. There are several volcanoes in the Andes, which would be the brothers. According to Wikipedia, Aconcagua is an easy climb from the north, but the other directions are very difficult and dangerous.

The other names refer to:

> The Harrison family is the [Himalayas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himalayas), the tallest mountains in the world.
>  The Rabey family is the [Rocky Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Mountains), the major mountain chain in North America.
>  The Aces are the [Alps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocky_Mountains), in Europe.

From the hint, the surnames

> have the same first letter as the mountain chains they refer to.

Comment: You almost have it... Check the question again... (You already won the +1, now won the check)

Comment: I feel it would be unfair to post an answer separately since Herb already did all the work here but I think rot13(Gur dhrfgvba nfxf jub nz V; fb vg'f ybbxvat sbe n fvatyr nafjre. Guhf gur gnyyrfg zbhagnva va gur Nycf vf Zbhag Oynap.)

Comment: @MatíasRodríguez updated. I forgot about the second paragraph when I initially posted.

Comment: Good spot. Note it's not just the initial of each surname, but the length as well...

Comment: Now you have it... Congrats!